# How can I set a custom attribute on completeNewPassword?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I have the following code

```
Auth.completeNewPassword(
        user,
        this.profileForm.get('newPassword')?.value,
        {
          "phone_number": String(this.profileForm.get('phone')?.value),
          "given_name": this.profileForm.get('fName')?.value,
          "family_name": this.profileForm.get('lName')?.value,
          "locale": this.profileForm.get('language')?.value,
          "custom:role": "user" // Error when this line is added
        }
      )
      .then(data => console.log("Changed Password! -->", data))
      .catch(err => console.log("Password change failed: ", err));
```

It fails at the `custom:role` line and I get the following error:

```
`Input attributes include non-writable attributes for the client XXXX`
```

Also, in Cognito, the role attribute doesn't show as a required attribute. How can I set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my previous answer was incorrect, so I deleted it for posterity.

Apparently we have to set the Read and Write permissions of the custom attribute before we can set it using Amplify.

Cool - where do we have this setting? **NOT** in the Attributes tab of the Cognito Console. It is tucked away in **APP CLIENTS** tab all the way at the bottom under a toggle called `Set attribute read and write permissions`. Check the boxes of your custom attribute and you have it.

Terrible UX but at least I have the answer now.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=882666